# Assigning .value to CSS style

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im working on a little project.

Here's the thing.
I want to have textfields to be read and then the value's I read out of it need to be assigned to a css rule.

i.e.

```
    document.getElementById("BD").value;
```

I want that value that is being read to be assigned to border-radius.

```
   .style.border-radius:<VALUE>px;
```

but how to make that link.

Then If i have 3 divs all of them have seperate names how can I fix that they only assign to the div I selected?

EDIT:
Complete HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Opdracht 1</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
<script language="javascript">
function BorderDikte(){
    document.getElementById("BD").value;
    document.getElementById("BS").value;
    document.getElementById("BK").value;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<table width="750" border="1" cellspacing="3" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td width="318">Border dikte (thin, medium, thick)</td>
    <td width="419"><textarea id="BD"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Border soort (dashed, dotted, solid or double)</td>
    <td><textarea id="BS"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Border kleur (bijvoorbeeld #000 of #FFF</td>
    <td><textarea id="BK"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Welke Div? ( 1, 2 of 3)</td>
    <td><textarea id="DN"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;<button>Go</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;<button>Reset</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;<button>Onzichtbaar</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT 2:

I have to rexplain I guess...

Example

```
[] [] []

Border = thick
Border color = #0F0
Border style = Solid
Which div = 2
Press go
```

The values are now being read and then being proccessed into my CSS
So that the 2nd div (div 2) is now adjusted.

```
[] **[]** []

     ^
     Red and solid

Border       = [textfield empty]
Border color = [textfield empty]
Border style = [textfield empty]
Which div?   = [textfield empty]
```

Comment: You'll need to use Javascript for this.

Comment: Can you include your full relevant HTML and CSS code? It's hard to understand the exact situation from your description.

Comment: reposting this answer.

Comment: Yes, please edit your question to include that code.

Answer (score 0):

like so:

**HTML**

```
<div id = "one"></div><div id = "two"></div><div id = "three"></div>
```

---

**Javascript**

```
var bordRad = parseInt(document.getElementById("BD").value, 10);
document.getElementById("one").style.borderRadius = bordRad + "px";
```

i may have misunderstood your question though, please clarify, and/or add some of your code.

Comment: @Mr_Green ye i know it doesnt work im not writing a program for him i am giving him the general gist

Comment: arghh.. your syntax was wrong. Atleast you should have explained it in words instead of showing it in programming. Anyway, leave it .

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight

Just insert the border properties in a textfield and let it change those properties in the CSS. So that the border changes to what you filled in

Comment: you have to take the box's value as a variable and assign the variable to the box's .style.borderRadius what dont you understand? are you sure you know how javascript works?